# Component-based design C++?

Tags: c++, list, callback, components, functor

I am trying to work with a componenent-based model. Essentially, I want to have an object that I can attach other objects to, and then through the root object access all of the functions in the child objects. For example: If I have an object called Calculator, and then I have 2 others called Add, and Subtract, I want to be able to simply attach the Add and Subtract objects to the Calculator object, and then be able to do something like Calculator.add(), which actually calls Calculator.Add.add();

I have heard that callbacks using functors are the way to go with this. Is this true? If so, is there a way to grab a list of all current available functors on an object?

I have been looking into working with set up similiar to this :

```
#include <callback.h>   //include the callback library header
#include <iostream.h>

class Button{
public:
Button(const Functor0 &uponClickDoThis)
    :notify(uponClickDoThis)
    {}
void click()
    {
    notify();   //a call to operator()
}
    private:
    Functor0 notify;    //note - held by value
    };

    //Some application stuff we'd like to connect to Button:


    class CDPlayer{ 
    public:
       void play(){cout<<"Playing"<<endl;}
       void stop(){cout<<"Stopped"<<endl;}
    };

    void wow()
       {cout<<"Wow!"<<endl;}

    void main()
{
CDPlayer cd;

//makeFunctor from object and ptr-to-member-function

Button playButton(makeFunctor(cd,&CDPlayer::play));
Button stopButton(makeFunctor(cd,&CDPlayer::stop));

//makeFunctor from pointer-to-function

Button wowButton(makeFunctor(&wow));

playButton.click(); //calls cd.play()
stopButton.click(); //calls cd.stop()
wowButton.click();  //calls wow()
}
```

Comment: You might want to check out e.g. [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).